# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable while using dict( )

Tags: python

I was using Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2. The code shown below fails with the following error. I searched a lot about this but I'm unable to find why is it happening.

```
>>> bob=dict(name='bob smith',age=42,pay='10000',job='dev')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: Have you named a variable `dict` somewhere?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In a fresh interpreter:

```
>>> bob=dict(name='bob smith',age=42,pay='10000',job='dev')
>>> bob
{'age': 42, 'pay': '10000', 'job': 'dev', 'name': 'bob smith'}
```

However, you are getting a `TypeError`:

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

This error you get tells you that **your** `dict` is not callable.

Since **my** `dict` is callable when I open a fresh interpreter, it means that **your** `dict` is different.

Most likely, you defined a `dict` variable, which overrode the built-in `dict`. Look for the

```
dict = {...}
```

line, and rename your variable.

As pointed out by [@Robᵩ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41605608/7051394), don't use built-in names for your variables. Especially avoid the tempting `str`, `list`, and so on.

Comment: Yes the problem was with the variable name dict , when i deleted the previously defined dict  and then used it again the code works perfectly fine

Comment: I had the same problem, thank you for clearly explaining that my dict and your dict are not the same

Comment: Great answer. Someone should write in the docs that using built in names prevents you from using the function.

Answer (score 10):

On a previous line in that interactive session, you have rebound the `dict` name to some variable. Perhaps you have a line like `dict={1:2}` or `dict=dict(one=1, two=2)`.

Here is one such session:

```
>>> dict=dict(one=1)
>>> bob=dict(name='bob smith',age=42,pay='10000',job='dev')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
>>>
```

As a general rule, one should not use built-in type names as variable names, to prevent this error.

Answer (score 6):

edit: Ignore this, I am told this is bad practice.

As mgilson stated, the issue is likely that you have a variable called dict. The solution to this would be to run

```
del dict
```

which deletes the variable by that name.

Comment: @Rightleg, Thanks for pointing that out. Added a disclaimer saying I am wrong.