# Inconsistent handling of dict function. TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, dictionary

I am cleaning up a piece of code on a new machine and I hit an error that makes no sense to me, since I know that the code ran fine on my old machine.

Here is the code, taken straight from the Python documentation on the dict funtion:

```
c = dict(zip(['one', 'two', 'three'], [1, 2, 3]))
```

Running this throws back an error:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

What makes this even more confusing is that I can run the code if it is the first thing I run. However, if I run the rest of my code first then the above code no longer runs - even in isolation. Is this a bug?

Version of Python: Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Because somewhere else in your code you have `dict = foo`.

Comment: Be sure you haven't defined any dictionary called `dict`.

Comment: Thanks both! I figured this out shortly after posting when looking over my code. Weird that I have never encountered this issue before now but every day is a learning day

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable while using dict( )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605525/typeerror-dict-object-is-not-callable-while-using-dict)

Answer (score 1):

After posting this question, I have worked out the issue!

In my code, I define a loop that uses a variable called 'dict'. This defines 'dict' as a variable and the dict() function no longer works because it seems to be overwritten by my variable.

I was under the impression that certain words are protected in Python to prevent people from accidentally redefining a core feature, but that does not seem to apply in this case.

I have now fixed my issue, but I am open to input from anyone who cares to share!

Comment: Here you are the list of python keywords: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_keywords.asp

Comment: And here's the list of words that are **not** protected: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html. These are just built-in functions (or classes) and you're free to change them, under your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

Try entering bare `dict` immediately before your line that reads `c = dict(zip(['one', 'two', 'three'], [1, 2, 3]))`. The command's output should read `<class 'dict'>`. If it's anything else, it was modified from its initial value.

Similarly, try entering `type(dict)` to check for `dict`'s type. The output should read `<class 'type'>`.

Overriding Python's built-in names is unfortunately permitted and can lead to hard-to-diagnose bugs. For example, `tuple` is a [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple), and it's therefore better to name a variable `t` or `tpl` rather than `tuple`. For a concrete example, the code `[set(tuple) for tuple in [(1, 2), (3, 4)]]` works fine and doesn't redefine `tuple` outside of the list comprehension, but it would be better to write `[set(tpl) for tpl in [(1, 2), (3, 4)]]`.